# fullCalendar and RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, events, fullcalendar

fullCalendar is a calendar plugin that takes an array of objects, and make them into events to be rendered onto it's own calendar. One of the properties is **eventDrop**, which allows dragging and dropping of events on a calendar.

Whenever eventDrop occurs, my function will do a $.post to write to my db the changed date. However, I'm given the following error.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
Extend [jQuery]
Extend [jQuery]
...
Extend [jQuery]
```

This is my function.

```
$('#taskCalendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        height: calendarheight = $(window).height() - $("#nav").height() - 140,
        events: courseTasks,
        editable: true,
        eventStartEditable: true,
        eventDurationEditable: false,
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                        tbLoadData(event["id"]);
                    },
        eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {

    // Format date for DB
    var newStart = new Date(event["start"]);
    var new_due_date = newStart.format("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss");
    event["due_date"] = new_due_date;

    // Update in DB
    updateToDB(event);

}
    });

function updateToDB(data) {

    $.post("./php/controllers/retrieval.php?fn=dsb_modify_task", data, function(data,status){
        $.notify(data.task_name + " is saved\n" + data + "\n" + status , "success");
    });
}
```

What's weird is that $.post works everywhere else. Except in this function. Has anyone experienced something similar to this? I've had no luck trying to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Do not send the event that comes from the eventDrop function. It has some values that are calculated through function calls.

You must create a new event objects (`var new_event = {}`) and copy the attributes that you want to send to your server. Then you can send this new object without exceeding the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it's because you're sending the event object as the post data. You have to filter the event object, for example, by creating another object with only the properties you need as id, title, start, end and allDay and send it as the post data ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with delete event.source property. Simply delete it and you are good:

```
  eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    delete event.source;
    return $.post("/edit-event/" + event.id, event, function(data) {...}}
```